# Sull'uso figurato di "fuoco di sbarramento"

Tags: word-usage

Su [questo articolo di Euronews](http://it.euronews.com/2017/02/03/usa-ue-fuoco-di-sbarramento-contro-il-prossimo-ambasciatore-di-trump/) si può leggere

> USA-UE: **fuoco di sbarramento** contro il prossimo ambasciatore di Trump

e poi

> Nemmeno nominato, e già protagonista di un **fuoco di sbarramento**, anche se non si può dire che sia suo malgrado: il loquace forse prossimo ambasciatore degli Stati Uniti presso l’Unione europea, Ted Malloch, ha rilasciato una serie di interviste in cui ha detto chiaramente quello che pensa dell’Unione europea, e non sono cose che Bruxelles possa condividere, anche se alcune interpretazioni sono forse andate un po’ al di là delle parole effettivamente pronunciate.

La mia domanda è sull'uso figurato che se ne fa dell'espressione "fuoco di sbarramento". Il suo significato si può più o meno capire dal contesto, ma non ho trovato nulla su questo uso figurato nei dizionari che ho consultato. Si tratta di un uso comune o è piuttosto un'invenzione del giornalista che ha scritto questo articolo? Potreste farmi qualche altro esempio?

Comment: Ho l'impressione che questo uso si sia diffuso in italiano come calco semantico dall'inglese *barrage* (che oltre al corrispondente senso letterale è anche “an overwhelming number of questions, criticisms, or complaints delivered simultaneously or in rapid succession: a barrage of questions”).

Comment: Barrange: Artillery sense is 1916, from World War I French phrase tir de barrage "barrier fire" intended to isolate the objective. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=barrage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'espressione ha chiaramente un'origine nel gergo militare, probabilmente risale al periodo  della Prima Guerra Mondiale a vedere dai risultati di [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fuoco%20di%20sbarramento&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfuoco%20di%20sbarramento%3B%2Cc0). Il primo uso figurato che ho trovato è abbastanza recente, anni 90, ma  molto probabilmente ci sono esempi precedenti:

Da [I comunisti italiani tra Hollywood e Mosca: la sfida della cultura di massa ...](https://books.google.it/books?id=gA-KdWRFrVsC&pg=PA86&dq=%22fuoco%20di%20sbarramento%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjst_uNpvbRAhUJJ8AKHVgEA3wQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22fuoco%20di%20sbarramento%22&f=false) 1995:

> - ***Contro il fuoco di sbarramento della propaganda degli avversari la sinistra si trovò costretta in posizione difensiva.***  L'Urss non era in grado di offrire aiuti pari a quelli degli Stati Uniti e inoltre la sua reputazione quale campione dell'autodeterminazione e dell'antifascismo aveva subito un duro colpo nel febbraio 1948 in  ...

Da: [Mario Martinelli nel secolo delle contraddizioni](https://books.google.it/books?id=Q3sruA_C3HEC&pg=PA211&dq=%22fuoco%20di%20sbarramento%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkwJm2p_bRAhWJuhQKHZR_Ck0Q6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=%22fuoco%20di%20sbarramento%22&f=false) 2004:

> - Contraddicendo l'ispirazione sturziana e degasperiana regionalista, Centrismo popolare, in sintonia coi liberali e con la socialdemocrazia, ***diede inizio ad un fuoco di sbarramento contro l'introduzione delle regioni a statuto ordinario.***

La frase è  abbastanza comune e di facile comprensione e viene usata soprattutto in  contesti politici ed economici, ma non solo, come si può vedere nell' esempio che segue:

Da: [Attenti al lupo!: aggressività e bullismo tra i giovani](https://books.google.it/books?id=t0OCUkgr9nIC&pg=PA83&dq=%22fuoco%20di%20sbarramento%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU152GqPbRAhVD6xQKHTPnC04Q6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=%22fuoco%20di%20sbarramento%22&f=false) 2007:

> - Era proprio questo che sconcertava Sofia, che la faceva vergognare: ***se qualcuno osava toccarla, lei faceva fuoco di sbarramento, ma nel profondo sentiva una sorta di eccitazione piacevole***, che non poteva confidare a nessuno. Era per allontanare questa sensazione che aveva scritto il biglietto. Ma ora non sapeva più se ...